# How should I go about cleaning and restoration after brush fire damage?

Tags: fire

My neighborhood is the victim of the Coastal fires a few months back. Our house has some soot around the windows, a few windows are also bent. We changed out the insulation in the attic, and also replaced the furnaces as well as the AC units outside.

While we know we need someone to clean the house, do we need to hire a restoration company? We have not found one that we trust yet but our insurance company is eagerly seeking a name. We have a few cleaning companies that we like. Just wondering the variances in the level of cleaning.

We are high risk health individuals so are proactively replacing the furnaces. Do you think we should replace the drywall as well? No fire occurred in our house but the house still smells like smoke after months and after using industrial fans.

Thanks,

Comment: Not an expert, so just a comment: I'd suspect more permanent smoke damage in anything fabric-like - carpets, rugs, curtains, etc. Drywall should be relatively immune, and a coat of paint would likely help a lot too.

Comment: Note that a flood situation is different because water can cause permanent damage to drywall and dirty water can lead to mold, etc. But drywall is actually pretty good when it comes to fires.

Comment: Drywall replacement after fires tends to be "fires in the house that were put out with water, causing water damage." Seal and paint is not a bad option.

Comment: You've asked several broad and opinion-based questions here. We're not a discussion forum, and product and service recommendations are off topic. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd replace a furnace here. Metal parts can be cleaned. That seems like a knee-jerk response.

Comment: leftover forest fire smells, while not pleasant, should not be as harmful/risky as leftover house fire smells. Burnt wood is commonly encountered by humans historically, burnt carpet and shingles and a bevy of other chemicals are not.

Answer (score 1):

For lingering odors, you need (IMHO) an industrial-strength ozone generator, which a "restoration company" will typically have, but you can also buy or rent one. Take care not to be in the space where it's operating when it's operating. Those aggressively oxidize whatever is around, including odor molecules.

Removing any carpet/upholstery, or at least cleaning the heck out of it (and not just the use surfaces, for upholstered furniture - everything) is utterly required. The ozone treatment can also help, but replace what's not of great sentimental value first.

Finally, does it still smell of smoke outside? As long as it does, inside will not be clear of that.

Answer (score 0):

Laser cleaning seems to be the best modern choice.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTgPqZUPPyI

---

> also replaced the furnaces as well as the AC units outside

Assuming these were still in working order then I'm sorry that you've already done this but the outdoor A/C unit has no effect on air quality inside the home. A routine deep-clean would have sufficed. If the insurance paid for it then I guess it doesn't matter to you though.

Same thing for the furnace. The ductwork is what needs to be truly cleaned or replaced.